# Mobile Safari not zooming on orientation change?

Tags: jquery, ios, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I'm working on a web application which I wish to have fill the entire viewable area of a browser, with no scrolling. I've accomplished this with a viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

This seems to have the desired effect on every browser except Mobile Safari. On Safari, I have two problems:

1. The bottom of the page hangs about 60px below the bottom of the window in portrait mode, and about 120px in landscape mode. I assume this is because of Safari's address bar being counted as part of its viewable area, but can you verify this and how can I get around it without affecting other browsers?
2. The page content does not resize itself correctly after the orientation changes. I'm given a large gutter along the right side of the page.

If it makes any difference, I'm using jQuery Mobile and this is a `page` object with a `panel` on the left side. None of these bugs are present in Chrome for Android or Browser.apk.

Edit: page can be found at http://bit.ly/19LoH8m.

Thanks.
Scott

Comment: can you provide us a link or a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: check this one first, http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by removing the `width` and `height` properties from the viewport. It now renders correctly on Mobile Safari, Chrome (for iOS, desktop, and Android), and IE10.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update these first and let's see.

Instead of

```
$("#mapViewer").outerHeight($(window).innerHeight());
```

Use

```
$("#mapViewer").outerHeight($(window).height());
```

See JQ doc, http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/

And there is also orientation change event in JQM,
Instead of

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    /* some calculation */
});
```

Use

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
    /* some calculation */  
});
```

Comment: Actually Mobile Safari's inspector is returning the same value for both height methods, and switching them has no effect. However, I did find a fix - I simply removed the viewport tag. Will post that as an answer now and mark it as accepted when I finish cross-browser testing it.